# JAVASCRIPT nested loops - triangle exercise from user input

Tags: javascript, loops, nested-loops

I am trying to figure out a triangle excercise where the user inputs a number and the triangle is then created based on said number ex enter 5
This is what I want

**5

6 6

7 7 7

8 8 8 8

9 9 9 9 9

10 10 10 10 10**

Each line the number is increased by 1. I can't get my code to increase by 1.
I keep getting

5

5 5

5 5 5

5 5 5 5

5 5 5 5 5

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

```js
let num = prompt("Enter a number");

//Check if its a number
num = parseInt(num);

//loop 1
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

  //loop 2
  for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {
    document.write(num);
  }

  document.write(num = num +1; "<br>");
}
```

```html
<p id="num"> </p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I can't get my code to increase by 1"*?  Looking through your code line by line and operation by operation, what specifically isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: edited my post ... so hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: So you want to add `1` to `num` between each row?  Have you tried anything to make that happen?  Where are you attempting to add `1` to `num`?

Comment: I've edited by final document.write (num +1) with and without quotes. tried a couple other things too

Comment: "I can't get my code to increase by 1" But you did nothing to make `num` increase by 1. There is literally 6 lines of code. Debugging is an essential part of programming, just do num  = num + 1; at the end of the loop

Comment: @lostgirl: Where in the code shown are you doing that?  In the code you're showing us, you are successfully adding 1 to `i` and successfully adding 1 to `y`, but asking how to add 1 to `num`.  You are encouraged to *try something*.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the entered number as the loop upper limit:

```js
let num = prompt("Enter a number");

//Check if its a number
num = parseInt(num);

//loop 1
for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

  //loop 2
  for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {
    document.write(num);
  }

  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: so I want the input to be the number displayed and 6 as the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is entirely invalid:

```
document.write(num = num +1; "<br>");
```

You're somehow confusing *calling a function* with *defining a `for` loop*.  Those are two entirely different things.

Don't randomly try to munge together separate operations.  Put each operation on its own line of code.  The two operations you want to perform are:

1. Add 1 to `num`
2. Output a `<br>` element

These are separate operations.  So separate them:

```
num = num +1;
document.write("<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be placing the incrementation of your num before writing it to the document. See the code below check the line between loops.

```js
let num = prompt("Enter a number");

//Check if its a number
num = parseInt(num);

//loop 1
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  //loop 2
  num++;
  for (let y = 0; y < i; y++) {
    document.write(num);
  }

  document.write("<br>");
}
```

```html
<p id="num"> </p>;
```